# WMAppManifest.xml Background Agent error

Tags: windows-phone, background-agent

I am getting a warning for WMAppManifest.xml file after i added a background agent task.
My xml is:

```
<ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
    <BackgroundServiceAgent Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" Name="MyAgent" Source="MyAgent" Type="MyAgent.ScheduledAgent" />
</ExtendedTask>
```

Background Agent Class file name - ScheduledTaskAgent

Background Agent Assembly name - myAgent

Background Agent Default namespace - myAgent

Can anyone point out the error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What warning do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. This might help those who have been stuck at the same problem.

**Steps**:

1. Create a Background Agent using the Template in Visual Studio.
2. In the main project, right click on solution and select add existing project
3. Then right click on main project, click on Add Reference, go to second tab 'Projects' and select the background agent.

The **third step** is the main step. I missed out on that step and hence the issue. 
The entry in WMAppManifest.xml will be **automatically** created.

Comment: It does not create the entry automatically in WP8 for some reason

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition for Windows Phone and I do development in WP7.5, listed the above steps as per that. No idea about WP8 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

this will probably sound strange but try to change name of background agent class to something else, e.g. ScheduledAgent. I think you might have name conflict there.